# How to import Formik?

Tags: reactjs

port './App.css';

function App() {
return (
<>

```
<div className='container'>
  
</div>

</>
```

);
}

ooooooo iiiiiii lk;jv

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react'
import { Field, Form, Formik} from 'formik';

function Add() {
return (

```
    <Formik
   initialValues={{ email: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', myPassword: '' }}
   onSubmit={(values) => {
       console.log(values)
   }}
 >
     <Form>
       <Field type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
       <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />
       <Field name="myPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password" />

       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </Form>
 </Formik>
```

)
}

export default Add

Comment: please do format your code

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hill-cmbz1?from-embed=&file=/src/Carousel.css:0-429

1. // App.js //

   import Carousel, { CarouselItem } from "./Carousel"; import gtr1
   from './assets/gtr.jpg'

   export default function App() {   return (

   ```
          <div className="image">
            <img src={gtr1}></img>

            <div className="txt">
              <h1> HeyyyyY!</h1>
            </div>
          </div>


        </CarouselItem>
      </Carousel>
    </div>   ); }
   ```

   // Carousel.js //

   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"; import {
   useSwipeable } from "react-swipeable";

   import "./Carousel.css";

   export const CarouselItem = ({ children, width }) => {   return (
   <div className="carousel-item" style={{ width: width }}>
   {children}
      ); };

   const Carousel = ({ children }) => {   const [activeIndex,
   setActiveIndex] = useState(0);   const [paused, setPaused] =
   useState(false);

   const updateIndex = (newIndex) => {
   if (newIndex < 0) {
   newIndex = React.Children.count(children) - 1;
   } else if (newIndex >= React.Children.count(children)) {
   newIndex = 0;
   }

   ```
    setActiveIndex(newIndex);   };
   ```

   useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
   if (!paused) {
   updateIndex(activeIndex + 1);
   }
   }, 3000);

   ```
    return () => {
      if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    };   });
   ```

   const handlers = useSwipeable({
   onSwipedLeft: () => updateIndex(activeIndex + 1),
   onSwipedRight: () => updateIndex(activeIndex - 1)   });

   return (
   <div
   {...handlers}
   className="carousel"
   onMouseEnter={() => setPaused(true)}
   onMouseLeave={() => setPaused(false)}
   >
   <div
   className="inner"
   style={{ transform: `translateX(-${activeIndex * 100}%)` }}
   >
   {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
   return React.cloneElement(child, { width: "100%" });
   })}


   <button
   onClick={() => {
   updateIndex(activeIndex - 1);
   }}
   >
   Prev

   {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
   return (
   <button
   className={`${index === activeIndex ? "active" : ""}`}
   onClick={() => {
   updateIndex(index);
   }}
   >
   {index + 1}

   );
   })}
   <button
   onClick={() => {
   updateIndex(activeIndex + 1);
   }}
   >
   Next


      ); };

   export default Carousel;

   // Carousel.css //

   *{   margin: 0; } .carousel {
   overflow: hidden;   }
   .inner {
   white-space: nowrap;
   transition: transform 1s;   }
   .carousel-item {
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;

   ```
    color: #fff;   }
     .indicators {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;   }
     .indicators > button {
    margin: 5px;   }
     .indicators > button.active {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;   }
     .image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;   }   .image{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
   ```

   }   .txt{
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
   align-items: center;

   ```
       }   .txt h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: aqua;
    margin-bottom: 200px;   }
   ```

Comment: please format your code